# Android swipe tab with scroller

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, swipe

i'm using a Material swipe tab to show with swipe 3 different fragment layout.
This is the xml layout for swipe tab:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now the xml layout fragment of swipe have a button fixed into bottom of layout so when i swipe to this fragment the layout of fragment is cut see image:

there some way to fix the layout fragment into ViewPager or a way for scroll it with a scroller view?

Thanks

Comment: You can use scrollView in fragment.Or use a RelativeLayout in fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second `Fragment`, you can use

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});
```

To scroll your `ScrollView` to the bottom, so your `Button` will be totally visible.

Comment: scrollView must be define by R.id?

Comment: Inside your fragment, you do `ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) yourRootView.findViewById(R.id.yourScrollViewId);`.

Comment: Ok but the Scroll View must be add into layout of ViewPager?

Comment: No, in your fragment layout. You can make it as parent/root view.